# Internal server error when calling Laravel API from Next.js page

Tags: laravel, next.js, laravel-8

I have a working API in Laravel. Tested using Postman.

The Laravel project folder and the Next.js project folder are inside the same parent `laravel-next` folder. (Laravel is served at `localhost:8000` and Nextjs is served at `localhost:3000`)

To get list of all items I use this API endpoint: `http://localhost:8000/api/products/`.
This is the `php artisan route:list` output:

```
+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                    | Name             | Action                                         | Middleware |
+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------|
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/products           | products.index   | App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@index   | api        |
|        | POST      | api/products           | products.store   | App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@store   | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/products/{product} | products.show    | App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@show    | api        |
|        | PUT|PATCH | api/products/{product} | products.update  | App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@update  | api        |
|        | DELETE    | api/products/{product} | products.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@destroy | api        |
```

I already inserted a few rows to the `products` table and this is how my `api/products` `GET` method looks like:

```
public function index()
{
    return ProductResource::collection(Product::all());
}
```

It works because when I manually type in the browser `localhost:8000/api/products` the JSON object with the products is displayed.

But when I try to call the API from the Next code, I get `500 (Internal Server Error)`.

This is the `product.jsx` code:

```
function Product({ data }) {        
  }      
  
  export async function getServerSideProps() {
    // Fetch data from external API
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/products/`, {
      method: 'GET',
      mode:'cors',
    })
    const data = await res.json()        
  
    // Pass data to the page via props
    return { props: { data } }
  }
  
  export default Product
```

Comment: Are you using any auth?

Comment: nope, clean Laravel project for testing, even commented out the `Route::middleware('auth:api')` line from `api.php`

Comment: Have you set your headers?

Comment: I don't think so, where do I do it, and how?

Comment: Update: I found the issue: I did not return anything in the render function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue: I just did not have any code in the `render` function of the React component. I need to return something:

```
function Product({ data }) {    
    //return something here!
    return (
        <div>Some data</div>
    )
}      
  
//rest of the code remains the same
```